# Saving to PDF in android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I am working on an engineering app and How can I save the calculations my android app has performed in pdf? When the user has provided the input and hits the button for results, I want to display the result and provide the option of saving the calculations performed to PDF. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Two different approaches are provided by droidText and Docmosis Cloud services depending on your implementation options / desires.  droidText runs locally whereas Docmosis offloads the work to a cloud service (meaning integration with your app is easy but you need to be web-connected to produce your PDF).  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Hope that helps.